# Python Running Bash Script and Getting Output

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, terminal, subprocess

I need to run a bash script and get the output. The script has a loop with avariable.

It works on terminal screen when I paste bash script only, but it gives error when I use subprocess by using Python. Here is the code:

```
import subprocess

text1 = """
declare -a StringArray=("a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5" )
for val in ${StringArray[@]}; do
   echo $val
done
"""
text_output = (subprocess.check_output(text1, shell=True).strip()).decode()
```

This is the error:

```
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Traceback (most recent call last):
.
.
.
' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

What is the solution?

```
Python3.7, OS: Debian-like Linux, Kernel: 4.19.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message states: `/bin/sh ...`. Python does not use `bash` as you expect. It uses another shell. (On my system `sh` is `dash`.) And it seems that this other shell does not support the `StringArray=("a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5" )` syntax.

You can try to explicitly select `bash` like this:

```py
subprocess.check_output(text1, shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

(At least, `/bin/bash` works on my system.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **subprocess.Popen** in this case.

Below is the code that can help you achieve the above. Please let me know if you have any question.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> cmd = 'declare -a StringArray=("a1" "a2" "a3" "a4" "a5" );for val in ${StringArray[@]}; do echo $val; done'
>>> x=subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True)
>>> a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

Comment: It did not work with ```/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected``` error.